# Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, class Drupal\node\Entity\Node does not have a method "getCurrentUserId"

Tags: 9, upgrading

I upgraded from Drupal 8.9.20 to Drupal 9.59. All modules seem compatible (upgrade manager). The site is up and running, but if I try to add new content via node/add/article, this error appears.

> TypeError: call_user_func(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, class Drupal\node\Entity\Node does not have a method "getCurrentUserId" in call_user_func() (line 400 of /html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/FieldConfigBase.php)
> #0 /html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/FieldConfigBase.php(400): call_user_func('...', Object(Drupal\node\Entity\Node), Object(Drupal\Core\Field\Entity\BaseFieldOverride))
> #1 /html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/FieldItemList.php(169): Drupal\Core\Field\FieldConfigBase->getDefaultValue(Object(Drupal\node\Entity\Node))
> #2 /html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityStorageBase.php(271): Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList->applyDefaultValue()
> #3 /html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityStorageBase.php(129): Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->initFieldValues(Object(Drupal\node\Entity\Node), Array)
> #4 /html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityStorageBase.php(94): Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->doCreate(Array)
> #5 /html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityForm.php(370): Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->create(Array)
> #6 /html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/HtmlEntityFormController.php(73): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityForm->getEntityFromRouteMatch(Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatch), '...')
> #7 /html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Controller/FormController.php(58): Drupal\Core\Entity\HtmlEntityFormController->getFormObject(Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatch), '...')
> #8 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatch))
> #9 /html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(123): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
> #10 /html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(580): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}()
> #11 /html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(124): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext), Object(Closure))
> #12 /html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(97): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array)
> #13 /html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(169): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}()
> #14 /html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(81): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)
> #15 /html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(58): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
> #16 /html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(48): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
> #17 /html/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(106): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
> #18 /html/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(85): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
> #19 /html/core/modules/ban/src/BanMiddleware.php(50): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
> #20 /html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(48): Drupal\ban\BanMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
> #21 /html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(51): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
> #22 /html/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
> #23 /html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(718): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
> #24 /html/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
> #25 {main}

Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: See the instructions in https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3153455

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are missing an update hook (did you run update.php on every update step?), but if this is the only problem it can be easily fixed:

```
drush cedit | grep core.base_field_override.node.*.uid
```

Now you see base field overrides of the uid field (one for each content type).

Enter the number of the first item listed. You have to enter it blindly because we grepped the prompt.

Correct this line:

```
default_value_callback: 'Drupal\node\Entity\Node::getDefaultEntityOwner'
```

Save the file and repeat the procedure for the other base fields.

You can also do this by copy-pasting the configuration in the admin config UI (single export and import).